# How do I get Subversion configuration changes to take effect?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, svn

I am trying to configure my svn repository to automatically set the svn:keywords property on every file.

My understanding is that I just add these lines to the configuration file and every new .rb file that is added or imported to the svn will have the svn:keywords property.

`[miscellany]

enable-auto-props = true

[auto-props]

*.rb = svn:keywords = Author Revision Date Id`

At this point I am experiencing a couple problems.  The svn I am using was set up by someone who no longer works at the company(and we are no longer in contact with him).  We access our svn though Apache using the mod_dav_svn module.

My first problem is that I am unsure of which configuration file I need to change.  I put these lines in both the svnserve.conf file in our svn's directory and the /root/.subversion/config file.  Neither appeared to have any effect and I have been unable to find out how to determine which config file the svn is using.

The other issue I have is that if I am using the correct configuration file, how do I activate the changes?  I didn't find any consistently running processes that I would have to restart.  I tried restarting the Apache server and rebooting the entire server but that didn't appear to solve the problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first problem is that I am unsure of which configuration file I need to change.

These type of changes are usually made to each user's own ~/.subversion/config not on the server.

> how do I activate the changes?

Changes are activated immediately.  Most subversion clients re-read the configuration file between each operation.